# Foursquare API - can't get User (my own) check in history

Tags: node.js, foursquare

I have been referencing this https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/users/checkins 
to try and download my own check in history.

I was able to get their own example from the "getting started" page to work:

```
const request = require('request');

request({
  url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore',
  method: 'GET',
  qs: {
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
    ll: '40.7243,-74.0018',
    query: 'coffee',
    v: '20180323',
    limit: 1
  }
}, function(err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

When I tried to change this to get my own checkins by replacing the url above this endpoint, https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/checkins, it gives me an error requiring a version (even though it's not in the parameters docs).

I've left in the v param from the example and get this error: "A user is required to call this endpoint."  I have also tried changing the URL because some examples online had this/the docs say regarding the userid: "For now, only self is supported" I tried replacing the USER_ID with my userid and also tried this: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins, but it gives me the same error.

```
qs: {
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',     
    v: '20180323',
    user_id: 'userid'  //tried with self, tried without it
  }
```

I don't care about getting this to work as much as I do being able to download my own foursquare data.  The link that I was able to use about 5 years ago is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `client_id` and `client_secret` parameters in this API (User Auth API). Try the following parameters:

```
qs: {
  oauth_token: 'OAUTH_TOKEN',
  v: '20180323',
  user_id: 'self'
}
```

How to get `oauth_token`
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication